# pause css rendering step by step

Tags: css, browser, rendering, analysis, pause

When my page loads, things seem to jerk around a bit: some of the stylesheets are boilerplate, I don't want to mess with them, but I'd like to know what's causing specific objects to change size or position i.e. there's a default size or position, then some CSS selector is activated and causes it to change.... There aren't any scripts running that change CSS so what I'd like to do is see how the page rendering step by step is causing things to shift... is there a way to step through the element rendering step by step to see exactly when the browser thinks it needs to move things around?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111819/how-to-pause-browser-rendering-until-css-is-computed

Comment: put some sample code